# Combine list of matrices into a big.matrix

Tags: r, matrix, r-bigmemory

I have a list of large (35000 x 3) matrices in R and I want to combine them into a single matrix but it would be about 1 billion rows long and would exceed the  [maximum object size in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984283/maximum-size-of-a-matrix-in-r).

The [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) package allows for larger matrices but [doesn't appear](https://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigmemory/issues/35) to support `rbind` to put multiple matrices together.

Is there some other package or technique that supports the creation of a very large matrix from smaller matrices?

Also before you ask this is not a RAM issue, simply an R limitation even on 64-bit R.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement it with a loop:

```
library(bigmemory)

## Reproducible example
mat <- matrix(1, 50e3, 3)
l <- list(mat)
for (i in 2:100) {
  l[[i]] <- mat
}

## Solution
m <- ncol(l[[1]])  ## assuming that all have the same number of columns
n <- sum(sapply(l, nrow))

bm <- big.matrix(n, m)
offset <- 0
for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  mat_i <- l[[i]]
  n_i <- nrow(mat_i)
  ind_i <- seq_len(n_i) + offset
  bm[ind_i, ] <- mat_i
  offset <- offset + n_i
}

## Verif
stopifnot(offset == n, all(bm[, 1] == 1))
```

Comment: Seems like a sensible solution, did you ever get to try it out @falcs? I have a similar problem, but I also want the big.matrix to be filebacked.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but a little more than a comment: are you sure that you can't do it by brute force?  R now has long vectors (since version 3.0.0; the question you link to refers to R version 2.14.1): from [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html),

> Arrays (including matrices) can be based on long vectors provided each of their dimensions is at most 2^31 - 1: thus there are no 1-dimensional long arrays.

while the underlying atomic vector can go up to 2^52 -1 elements ("in theory .. address space limits of current CPUs and OSes will be much smaller").  That means you should in principle be able to create a matrix that is as much as `((2^31)-1)/1e9` = 2.1 billion rows long; since the maximum "long" object size is about 10^15 (i.e. literally millions of billions), a matrix of 1 billion rows and 3 columns should (theoretically) not be a problem.