# Minimum absolute difference between vector pairs (greedy algorithm)

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, combinations, greedy

Given a numeric vector, I'd like to find the smallest absolute difference in combinations of size 2. However, the point of friction comes with the use of `combn` to create the matrix holding the pairs. How would one handle issues when a matrix/vector is too large?

When the number of resulting pairs (number of columns) using `combn` is too large, I get the following error:

> Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) :
> invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)

[This post states that the size limit of a matrix is roughly one billion rows and two columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984283/maximum-size-of-a-matrix-in-r)

Here is the code I've used. Apologies for the use of `cat` in my function output -- I'm solving the [Minimum Absolute Difference in an Array](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-absolute-difference-in-an-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=greedy-algorithms) Greedy Algorithm problem in HackerRank and R outputs are only counted as correct if they're given using `cat`:

```
minimumAbsoluteDifference <- function(arr) {
  combos <- combn(arr, 2)
  
  cat(min(abs(combos[1,] - combos[2,])))
}

# This works fine
input0 <- c(3, -7, 0)

minimumAbsoluteDifference(input0) #returns 3

# This fails
inputFail <- rpois(10e4, 1)

minimumAbsoluteDifference(inputFail) 
  #Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  # invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
```

Comment: if you can use Rcpp, then you should be able to to do this in less than a fraction of a second

Comment: @Onyambu, no need for `Rcpp`.... base `R` is plenty enough and in one line. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No need for `combn` or the like, simply:

```
min(abs(diff(sort(v))))
```

#### The Nitty Gritty

Finding the difference between every possible combinations is `O(n^2)`. So when we get to vectors of length `1e5`, the task is burdensome both computationally and memory-wise.

We need a different approach.

> How about sorting and taking the difference only with its neighbor?

By first sorting, for any element *v<sub>j</sub>*, the difference *min |v<sub>j</sub> -  v<sub>j -/+ 1</sub>|* will be the smallest such difference involving *v<sub>j</sub>*. For example, given the sorted vector `v`:

```
v = -9 -8 -6 -4 -2  3  8
```

The smallest distance from `-2` is given by:

```
|-2 - 3| = 5
|-4 - -2| = 2
```

There is no need in checking any other elements.

This is easily implemented in base `R` as follows:

```
getAbsMin <- function(v) min(abs(diff(sort(v))))
```

I'm not going to use `rpois` as with any reasonably sized vector, duplicates will be produces, which will trivially give `0` as an answer. A more sensible test would be with `runif` or `sample` (`minimumAbsoluteDifference2` is from the answer provided by @RuiBarradas):

```
set.seed(1729)
randUnif100 <- lapply(1:100, function(x) {
    runif(1e3, -100, 100)
})

randInts100 <- lapply(1:100, function(x) {
    sample(-(1e9):(1e9), 1e3)
})

head(sapply(randInts100, getAbsMin))
[1]  586 3860 2243 2511 5186 3047

identical(sapply(randInts100, minimumAbsoluteDifference2),
          sapply(randInts100, getAbsMin))
[1] TRUE

options(scipen = 99)
head(sapply(randUnif100, getAbsMin))
[1] 0.00018277206 0.00020549633 0.00009834766 0.00008395873 0.00005299225 0.00009313226

identical(sapply(randUnif100, minimumAbsoluteDifference2),
          sapply(randUnif100, getAbsMin))
[1] TRUE
```

It's very fast as well:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a = getAbsMin(randInts100[[50]]),
               b = minimumAbsoluteDifference2(randInts100[[50]]),
               times = 25, unit = "relative")
Unit: relative
expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   a   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000  1.00000    25
   b 117.9799 113.2221 105.5144 107.6901 98.55391 81.05468    25
```

Even for very large vectors, the result is instantaneous;

```
set.seed(321)
largeTest <- sample(-(1e12):(1e12), 1e6)

system.time(print(getAbsMin(largeTest)))
[1] 3
 user  system elapsed 
0.083   0.003   0.087
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
minimumAbsoluteDifference2 <- function(x){
  stopifnot(length(x) >= 2)
  n <- length(x)
  inx <- rep(TRUE, n)
  m <- NULL
  for(i in seq_along(x)[-n]){
    inx[i] <- FALSE
    curr <- abs(x[i] - x[which(inx)])
    m <- min(c(m, curr))
  }
  m
}
# This works fine
input0 <- c(3, -7, 0)

minimumAbsoluteDifference(input0)  #returns 3
minimumAbsoluteDifference2(input0) #returns 3


set.seed(2020)
input1 <- rpois(1e3, 1)
minimumAbsoluteDifference(input1)  #returns 0
minimumAbsoluteDifference2(input1) #returns 0

inputFail <- rpois(1e5, 1)
minimumAbsoluteDifference(inputFail)   # This fails
minimumAbsoluteDifference2(inputFail)  # This does not fail
```