# Shortest Path calculations crashes with igraph r - maximum number of nodes?

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a maximum number of nodes for the `igraph::shortest.paths` function?

The following code crashes `Microsoft R Open 4.0.2` in `RStudio Version 1.4.1106` under Windows 10 with 128GB RAM.

**Questions:**

- Is this because of the functionality of `igraph`
- Does this have to do with the local RAM?
- What are alternatives? Perhaps using the `cppRouting` package?

  ```
    library(igraph)
    c1 <- sample(1:48000, 293631, replace=TRUE)
    c2 <- sample(1:48000, 293631, replace=TRUE)

    # column bind the two vectors
    el <- cbind(c1, c2)

    # convert matrix as an edgelist into an undirected graph 
    g <- graph.edgelist(el, directed=FALSE)

    # obtain distance matrix with shortest path between all pairs of nodes
    t <- shortest.paths(g)
  ```

Comment: I think you can get some hints from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9984283/12158757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the library `cppRouting` can handle bigger networks than `igraph` does on my Windows system.

```
library(cppRouting)
gr <-makegraph(cbind(el, 1),directed=FALSE) # add one to indicate tie-strength
outcome <- get_distance_pair(gr)
```

This will get you the shortest paths between the nodes in the edgelist `el`.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, igraph does not have robust checks in place for exceeding maximum data structure sizes. However, as a guideline, you can assume that anything that cannot be indexed with signed 32-bit integers will not work. This is the case for the matrix that your computation would return:

```
> log2(48000^2)
[1] 31.10149
```

When exceeding these sizes, problems such as crashes are especially likely on Windows, where the size of the `long int` type (currently used extensively by igraph internals) is 32 bits, even on 64-bit systems.

---

There is ongoing work to make the C core of igraph fully 64-bit ready and let it detect when maximum data structure sizes are exceeded. Unfortunately, it is unclear how or whether 64-bit support can be brought to igraph's R interface because R itself still does not support 64-bit integers. However, future versions should show an error instead of crashing when sizes are exceeded.